# Nav dropdown not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The dropdown in the navigation is not working. The html is as follows. Help will be appreciated.

```
<div class="row menu_bg">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">VB.Net</a></li>
       <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
             Java <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Swing</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">jMeter</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>

          </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your html is fine the only thing missing is the jQuery code and the bootstrap js, add these in the same order under your last `</div>`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the bootstrap and jquery libraries, they handle the logic for displaying the dropdown interface working example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row menu_bg">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VB.Net</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Java <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Swing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">jMeter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a `container` inside a `row` and content inside a `container`, I've corrected that. The correct hierarchy is `container` => `row` => `col-??-##. If you put it in any other order, it will malfunction. This should work. I'm assuming you've added the``tag for bootstrap.min.js (or whatever flavor you prefer) and`jquery`. If not, please do so.

```
<div class="container menu_bg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">SVN</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">VB.Net</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Java<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Swing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jMeter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```